# Property scopes in Spring

Tags: java, spring, properties, scope

If a defined a property in executable's -context.xml file this way:

```
<util:properties id = "props"><prop key="foo">bar</foo></util:properties>
```

what's the scope of the property? Is it visible everywhere within the process?

More generally: Where can I find any documentation on property scopes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

util:properties creates a java.util.Properities object which can be used anywhere as any other Spring bean:

```
<util:properties id="props">
   <prop key="foo">map</prop>
</util:properties>

<bean id="b1" class="test.B1">
   <property name="props" ref="props" />
</bean>

...

public class B1 {
    Properties props;

    public void setProps(Poperties props) {
        this.props = props;
    }
...
```